# List Index out of range in 2D array above 0

Tags: python

I am converting JSON files into data frames by using 2D array. However, after reading files and placing them in array indices, on index one I get an error.

The code I am using to loop is:

```
 for i in range(2500):

     datadays[1].append(json.loads(day1.readline())) 

Error: list index out of range
```

Script code:

```
from array import *

import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json

day1=open('day1','r')
day2=open('day2','r')
day3=open('day3','r')

datadays=[[]]

for i in range(1400):
 datadays[0].append(json.loads(day1.readline()))
for i in range(2500):
 datadays[1].append(json.loads(day2.readline()))
for i in range(1500):
 datadays[2].append(json.loads(day3.readline()))
```

Comment: You obviously need to change `datadays=[[]]` to `datadays=[[],[],[]]`.

Comment: Well, you've create a list with one position with one list with 0 elements inside. So datadays[0] works because is the list you created but datadays[1] doesn't because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment, you obviously need to change `datadays=[[]]` to `datadays=[[],[],[]]`.

Alternatively, you could choose a slightly more Pythonic way:

```
datadays = [
    [json.loads(day1.readline()) for i in range(1400)],
    [json.loads(day2.readline()) for i in range(2500)],
    [json.loads(day3.readline()) for i in range(1500)]
]
```

And don't forget to close the files:

```
day1.close()
day2.close()
day3.close()
```

Comment: Or use a `with` statement to automatically close the file: `with open('day1', 'r') as day1:`